# Eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues of symplectic matrix on $K^{2n}$ orthogonal?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I showed that for the standard hermitian form $\langle , \rangle _{I_n}$ on $\mathbb{C}^n$ the eigenvectors of distinct eigenvalues of a matrix associated to this hermitian form are orthogonal to each other.

Can something similar be said about the standard symplectic form on $K^{2n}$ ?